# Endogeneity problem in ols regression and causality

Tags: regression, machine-learning, least-squares, residuals, endogeneity

If in my model, the independent variables are uncorrelated with the error term, there is no endogeneity problem, and the residuals satisfy the OLS assumptions, can I say that this model identifies causality?

And in another scenario, when I encounter an endogeneity problem but cannot find suitable instrumental variables. Are there alternative ways to correct my regression model? How can I convince the reviewers that my regression equation is valid?

Comment: "Identifies causality" is not a precise term. Identification is done in reference to a specific estimand. Besides that, no endogeneity (aka exchangeability) is only one of other causal assumptions often required (together with positivity, consistency and no interference). It is also unclear what you mean by "the residuals satisfy the OLS assumptions".